# Swift: The unknown context in the response of decoding JSON in swift from nested array

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

During my useless attempts to decode this simple JSON file, I've always got this strange response which I do reckon because of some mistakes I do in my code. I want to rid of these errors in brackets and keep my response clean:

> vk_with_server_response.InitialPageViewController.(unknown context at $105a03c18).(unknown context at $105a03dd0)

The full response looks like this:

> Response(count: 32363, items: [vk_with_server_response.InitialPageViewController.(unknown context at $105a03c18).(unknown context at $105a03dd0).Inner(first_name: "Sonya", last_name: "Kargina"), vk_with_server_response.InitialPageViewController.(unknown context at $105a03c18).(unknown context at $105a03dd0).Inner(first_name: "Slava", last_name: "Kholod")])

Also, if anyone knows how to do the same by using the "class". I'd be glad to have a look because with classes I have no response at all.

```swift
struct Response: Decodable{
    let count:Int
    let items:[Inner]
  
    enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey{
        case items
        case count
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.count = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .count)
        
        var innerItems = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .items)
        var arrayInner = [Inner]()
        
        while !innerItems.isAtEnd{
             let nestedItems = try innerItems.decode(Inner.self)
             arrayInner += [nestedItems]
        }
        items = arrayInner
        
    }
}

struct Inner: Decodable {
    var first_name:String
    var last_name:String
    
    enum ListCodingKeys:String,CodingKey{
        case first_name
        case last_name
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ListCodingKeys.self)
        self.first_name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .first_name)
        self.last_name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .last_name)
    }
}

struct FirstLayerOfResponse: Decodable{
    let response: Response
}

//-----------------------

var jsonTest = """
        {
          "response": {
            "count": 32363,
             "items": [{
                "first_name": "Sonya",
                "last_name": "Kargina"
             }, {
                "first_name": "Slava",
                "last_name": "Kholod"
             }]
            }
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)! // our data in native format

do {
    let tryJS = try JSONDecoder().decode(FirstLayerOfResponse.self, from: jsonTest)
    print(tryJS.response)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: What is your question here, you say you have a error but it looks like it is not related to the posted code because the json decoding works fine? What is this vk_with_server_response? Could you post the code that generates the error?

Comment: "unknown context" is not an error here. That's completely normal. It's just saying there some type that it can't provide the full name of, which can happen for a few reasons. But you shouldn't need it. What result do you actually want?

Comment: If you want to print a struct in a particular way, you need to conform it to CustomStringConvertible, and implement `description`. That will let you make it print in the way you want. The default way of printing a struct doesn't promise to be useful.

Comment: @RobNapier
Yes, excuse me for this misconception. I just want a clear response without any premises. For example like this:
Response(count: 32363, items: [(first_name: "Sonya", last_name: "Kargina"), (first_name: "Slava", last_name: "Kholod")]).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ohhh, I don't know what part should I send because "vk_with_server_response" is just the name of the file. "

Comment: The problem is that your types are defined within a function, and the default `struct` description does not know how to show the function name within the hierarchy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74669436/1271826. So, either implement your own [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/) conformance, or move the type definitions out of the function.