# Having trouble with print output of object decoded with JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, codable

I'm trying to decode a JSON string in swift but having some weird issues accessing the properties once decoded.

This is the contents of the JSON file that I retrieve from a locally stored JSON file

```json
[
  {
    "word": "a",
    "usage": [
      {
        "partOfSpeech": "determiner"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this is the code to access the properties of the JSON file

```swift
struct WordDictionary : Codable {
    var word: String
    var usage: [Usage]
}

struct Usage: Codable {
    var partOfSpeech: String
}
                
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: FILE_NAME, withExtension: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        let jsonData = try decoder.decode([WordDictionary].self, from: data)
        print(jsonData[0].word) //Outputs "a"
        print(jsonData[0].usage) //Outputs "[MyApp.AppDelegate.(unknown context at $102a37f00).(unknown context at $102a38038).Usage(partOfSpeech: "determiner")]"

    } catch {
        print("error:\(error)")
    }
}
```

As you can see, when I try to `print(jsonData[0].usage)` I get a series of unknown data messages before I get the “Usage” property. When I print this line I just want to see `determiner`, I’m not sure what the preamble about the “unknown context” is all about.

I’m also running this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function of the `AppDelegate`.

I’m not sure what I’m missing. I've been trying to find a solution for a few days now and trying different approaches but still can’t get the desired output, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either print `jsonData[0].usage[0].partOfSpeech` to print that property and not the whole object or make Usage conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and add your wanted output in the `description` property

Comment: And for your next question please try to write a better more informative title, as you say yourself you _don’t_ have a problem with the decoding.

Comment: I could simply do print(jsonData[0].usage[0].partOfSpeech) but what I ultimately want to do is take jsonData and present it as valid JSON (without the "unknown context"). I also want to understand why I'm getting the "unknown context" messages in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr

You are seeing the “unknown context” in the description of the type, because it was defined inside a function. You can solve this by either moving those type definitions outside of the function or implementing your own [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/) conformance.

---

It's a matter of where you defined your types.

Consider:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        struct WordDictionary: Codable {
            var word: String
            var usage: [Usage]
        }

        struct Usage: Codable {
            var partOfSpeech: String
        }

        do {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let words = try JSONDecoder().decode([WordDictionary].self, from: data)
            print(words[0].usage)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

That produces:

> [MyApp.AppDelegate.(unknown context at $102bac454).(unknown context at $102bac58c).Usage(partOfSpeech: "determiner")]

That is saying that `Usage` was defined in some unknown context within the `AppDelegate` within `MyApp`. In short, it does not know how to represent the hierarchy for types defined within functions.

Contrast that with:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    struct WordDictionary: Codable {
        var word: String
        var usage: [Usage]
    }

    struct Usage: Codable {
        var partOfSpeech: String
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        do {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let words = try JSONDecoder().decode([WordDictionary].self, from: data)
            print(words[0].usage)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

Which produces:

> [MyApp.AppDelegate.Usage(partOfSpeech: "determiner")]

---

You can also add your own [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/) conformance:

```swift
struct WordDictionary: Codable {
    var word: String
    var usage: [Usage]
}

struct Usage: Codable {
    var partOfSpeech: String
}

extension Usage: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "Usage(partOfSpeech: \"\(partOfSpeech)\")" }
}

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        do {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json")!
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let words = try JSONDecoder().decode([WordDictionary].self, from: data)
            print(words[0].usage)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

Which produces:

> [Usage(partOfSpeech: "determiner")]

Through `CustomStringConvertible`, you can make the `print` format it however you want.

Comment: This makes sense, and gets rid of the "unknown context" message. But given your example, how would I get rid of the "MyApp.AppDelegate" part of the output? Ideally I'd like to just output "[Usage(partOfSpeech: "determiner")]". What causes the "MyApp.AppDelegate" to append?

Comment: Conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and set `description` to be whatever you want, as outlined in the second half of my answer. I just modified `description` to produce `Usage(partOfSpeech: "determiner")`. But you can tweak this to be whatever you want.

Comment: Re “causes” of “MyApp.AppDelegate”: It is there because it really is part of the fully qualified name. A `WordDictionary` defined in `AppDelegate` of `MyApp` has a fully qualified name of `MyApp.AppDelegate.WordDictionary`. It’s nice to have the fully qualified name, because you can see, at a glance, where it is defined and it avoids ambiguity (in case you have another `WordDictionary` defined elsewhere). Because the compiler can generally infer which one you intended from the context, we don’t often use this hierarchical syntax in our code. But it is useful info in `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a type to print nicely when you interpolate an instance of it into a string, you need to make it conform to [CustomStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible).

This protocol declares one property: `description` and when string interpolation encounters an object that conforms to it, it uses the string returned by `description` instead.

You need something like:

```
extension Usage: CustomStringConvertible
{
    var description: String 
    {
        return "{ \"partOfSpeech\" : \"\(partOfSpeech)\" }"
    }
}
```

if you want a JSON like<sup>*</sup> string to print.

An alternative would be to re-encode the object using a `JSONEncoder` and convert the data to a `String`. That's much heavier but might be a better option for more complex objects.

<sup>*</sup>JSON like because things like line feeds and tabs won't be replaced by escapes and `"` and `\` appearing in the string won't be escaped.